# How to decode password in SHA-1 (with salt) with AuthenticationManagerBuilder

Tags: spring, spring-security, passwords

Have a class which registers users

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    UserDAO userDAO;

    @Autowired
    private RoleDAO roleDAO;

    @Autowired
    private ShaPasswordEncoder shaPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void save(User user) {

        user.setPassword(shaPasswordEncoder.encodePassword(user.getPassword(),"mySalt"));
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
        roles.add(roleDAO.getOne(1L));
        user.setRoles(roles);
        userDAO.save(user);

    }

    @Override
    public User findByUsername(String username) {
        return userDAO.findByUsername(username);
    }
```

As you see I encode in Sha with salt.
Here I'm trying to encode

```
    @Bean
    public ShaPasswordEncoder getShaPasswordEncoder(){

        return new ShaPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void registerGlobalAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(getShaPasswordEncoder());
    }

So where can I specify a salt to decode the password?
```

Comment: The big question is why do you want to decode the password? Spring Security does not require it to authenticate users. It authenticates by comparing the hashed password with the values retrieved from UserDetailsService.

Answer (score 1):

You can't decode a hashed password. A hash function is a one way function. Thus there is no way of specifying a salt to decode.

Comment: With xml config it works

 `code
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsServiceImpl">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder">
                <salt-source system-wide="mySalt" />
            </password-encoder>

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>`
 so you wanna say than in java config its unreleased?

Comment: There you have configured the salt for encoding, not for decoding. If you meant that, you should clarify your question.

Comment: when the application worked with the xml configuration, the password decoded( salt) normal ,now I want to implement this in java config and looking for how